# Darts Game - подсчет очков

Tags: c#, алгоритм, visual-studio

Существует задача консольно реализовать подсчет очков в Дартсе:
Существуют две величины (координаты x и y) они получают значения и сравниваются с кругами, которые имеют определенный порог величины (ну классические круги в дартсе)

Сами интервалы значений, которые и определяет, куда попадет бросок (значение x и y) - больше 10 = 0,  меньше 10 = 1, меньше 5 = 5, меньше 1 = 10. Я пытался реализовать через конструкцию if, но я не могу выполнить все тест кейсы.

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

Так я хотел бы понять - существует ли способ точнее сравнивать интервалы, чтобы <10 и <5 не накладывались на друг друга.

```
public static int GetScore(double x, double y)
{
    if (x < 1 & y < 1)
    {
        return 10;
    }

    if (x < 5 & y < 5)
    {
        return 5;
    }

    if (x < 10 & y < 10)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас какая-то не стандартная доска для Дартс, а просто мишень с кольцами от 1 до 10?

Comment: Начните с меньших. Если попал в меньший — то проверять больший круг не нужно.

Comment: Код надо вставлять текстом, а не скриншотом. Ну и с мишенью и очками у вас [что-то не так](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%81).

Comment: @Kromster, колец там всего 3 (внутреннее, среднее и внешнее), также есть 4-ый интервал, но это просто не попадание в доску. Интервалы значений определяют в какое кольцо ты попал и тем самым начисляют балл.

Comment: @aepot,  ну это test case, так что я думал, что передача аргументов никому особо и не нужна.

Comment: Это какой-то TDD чтоли? А нерабочий код то где? Одни тесты. И вставьте код текстом, пожалуйста.

Comment: @aepot Вставил. "TDD" - для него тут слишком примитивное задание.

Comment: Этот код не скомпилируется, исправьте пожалуйста. Ну есть в C# аж 2 конструкции switch, которые могут сделать код красивее.

Comment: `GetScore(double x, double y)` - почему не `int` аргументы?

Comment: @aepot потому что так изначально и прописано в задании (я просто когда-то скачал пак заданий из интернета и сейчас у меня дошли руки до их решения).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно даже без корней :)

```
public static int GetScore(double x, double y)
{
    double r = x*x+y*y;
    
    if (r < 1)   return 10;
    if (r < 25)  return 5;
    if (r < 100) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Или

```
public static int GetScore(double x, double y)
{
    double r = x*x+y*y;
    return (r < 1) ? 1 : (r < 25) ? 5 : (r < 100) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Доска для дартса - круг. Чем ближе к центру - тем большо очков. Вам надо считать радиус того круга, куда попал дротик и исходить от него
Центр круга должен быть в 0:0.

```
public static GetScore(double x, double y){
    double r = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);

    if(r < 1) return 10;
    if(r < 5) return 5;
    if(r < 10) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```